# How can you re-initialize an array that was predefined with the value null in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am supposed to **complete** the below program that determines the size of an array based on the int input of the user.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int userInput = -1;
       int[] userData = null;
```

But the program starts by declaring the array as :
`int[] userData = null;`

It also starts by declaring the user input variable as -1:
`int userInput = -1;`

The problem of the program is based on re-initializing this array using the int variable scanned from the user as the length of the given array:
`userInput = scan.nextInt();`
So I tried to re-initizile the array using the new input:
`int[] userData  = new int[userInput];`
But unsurprisingly Java complains since the array was initialized before (and I'm not supposed to change that).

The question is, is there actually a way to build on the given code or do I have to delete their initial declarations and start over?

Comment: You can't declare the same variable twice.  You can assign a new value to `userData` or use a different name, but you can't create a second variable also called `userData`.

Comment: hi & welcome! :) Or replace `int userInput = -1;int[] userData = null;` with your assignment/intialization, or don't `int[] userData  = new int[userInput];` but just `userData  = new int[userInput];`

Comment: Putting the data type (`int[]` in your case) in front of the variable *declares a new variable* with the given name. If it already exists, then of course Java will complain. However, if you leave the data type out (using only `variableName`), then you *use* that variable. For example: `userData = new int[userInput]`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Oh!! It now worked! I wrote userData without the braces and the program is now fine. Thanks a lot. And thank you all. First post always sounds dumb :D.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to declare and initialize the variables as soon as you need them with appropriate values without having to reassign them:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int userInput = scan.nextInt(); // no need to set to -1
int[] userData = new int[userInput]; // no need to set to null
```

Comment: I guess working with already declared variables was part of the exercise - regardless of what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can continue writing your program like so:

```
int[] userdata = null;
userInput = … ;
userdata = new int[userInput];  // Create new array, and assign to the existing variable.
```

Verify.

```
System.out.println(userdata);
System.out.println(userdata.length);
```

The output of this code is similar to:

```
[I@3d3fcdb0
10
```